# Checking form fields against table fields access 2007

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access-2007

```
Private Sub Command34_Click()
    If Name.Text = [Table1.Name] and Address.Text = [Table1.Address] Then
        MsgBox "Match"
    Else
        MsgBox "No Match"

End Sub
```

I am trying to have my close button check to see if all fields match their value they started with and if they do it will close if they don't it will prompt them to either save or discard changes.

I have the entire close button working however I cannot seem to get the fields of the form to compare to the table.

Any help in this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: I am not able to call on the fields from the table. I haven't called on table fields from VBA before so I am sure I am missing declaring something

Comment: Is there actually a `.Text` property or do you have to use the `.Value` property on `Name` and `Address`?

Comment: And also, you have `Address.Txt` instead of `Address.Text`.

Comment: I have a Text box called Name. I am want to compare that to the Table field to make sure they match or do not.

Comment: I am not sure if I am going about it completely wrong but this is what seemed logical to me. Please feel free to show me a better way as I am obviously not doing something right.

Comment: I guess you are using an **Unbound** form, else your table will already be updated by the field changes, if you are using **Unbound** then you must have already accessed your Recordset to set the fields forms initially so you can refer to them in the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a property called 'Dirty' which gets set by Access to TRUE when a change is made but has not been saved.

The following code should work for you:

```
Private Sub cmdClose_Click()
    If Form.Dirty Then  'check if changes have been made
        Select Case MsgBox("Save changes?", vbQuestion + vbYesNoCancel)
        Case vbYes
            DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
        Case vbNo
            Form.Undo
            DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
        Case vbCancel
            'do nothing
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For my work ticket system, if a user needs to make an update to an existing ticket that already has been created in a table, I create a recordset with that row and compare the form field with the existing row.

```
Dim myR as Recordset
Dim strSQL as String

strSQL = "Select * From Work_Tickets Where ID = '" & Ticket_Number & "'"

Set myR = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, OpenDyanset)

If me.status = myR![Status] then
    msgbox "No changes have been made"
Else
    myR.Edit
    myR![Status] = me.status
    myR.Update
    msgbox "A change has been made"
End if

Set myR = Nothing
```